# Imageview randomise animations

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-animation

I have a set of 10 imageview animations out of which, I want to pick animation in random every time. How can I achieve that ?

Also, can someone point me towards working examples of complex android views animations. Combination of fade, appear, rotate and slide. Something like the animation shown here (http://www.factslides.com/). Any library in this regard would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your app's minimumSDK is 3.0+ you can do the following

1) define many `ObjectAnimator`s and `ObjectAnimatorSet`s (extends `ObjectAnimator`) and add them as values into a `HashMap` with key being an `Integer`.
2) write simple randomization logic which pulls `ObjectAnimator` from the `HashMap` by id.

I wrote sample `ObjectAnimator` code here: https://github.com/jshvarts/ObjectAnimator and `ViewPropertyAnimator` code here: https://github.com/jshvarts/ViewPropertyAnimator